# error code : java.lang.IllegalStateException: No output folder while running tomcat

Tags: error-handling, tomcat8.5

After installation when I am hitting the url 'hhtp://localhost:8080' I am facing this error.

> Type Exception Report
>
> Message java.lang.IllegalStateException: No output folder

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

**Exception**

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No
>   output folder
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:601)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:402)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   Root Cause
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No output folder
>     org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.createOutputDir(JspCompilationContext.java:687)
>     org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.getOutputDir(JspCompilationContext.java:202)
>     org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.getClassFileName(JspCompilationContext.java:535)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.isOutDated(Compiler.java:459)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.isOutDated(Compiler.java:425)
>     org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:588)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:368)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.

Answer (score 1):

Try running startup.bat as administrator. Worked for me.